# Python multithreaded program crashing without error

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, pytorch

I am trying to parallelize the load of the data and the learning in a pytorch project. From main thread I create 2 threads, one loading the next batch while the other is learning from the current batch. The loading threading is transferring the loaded data through a Queue.

**My problem** is: the program suddenly stops at random state of execution **without any error message** (debug execution or not). Sometimes at the first epoch, sometimes after 7 epoch (50min)... Is it possible to have an error message somehow ? Does anyone have encountered that problem ?

It makes me think about memory leakage, but I check all the code about the shared data. I have also seen things about prints not being thread safe so I removed them... Please also note that the code didn't had this problem before parallelization.

I am using:

- conda environement.
- Threading.thread
- pytorch
- Windows server

**Update**: Apparently the pytorch code referencing cuda learning doesn't like to be called from a separate thread. If I keep my cuda learning in the main thread, it stays alive...

**Code**: Since I have less unexpected crashes with the cuda learning in the main thread. I only kept one thread. (it also makes more sense)

part of the main:

```
        dataQueue = queue.Queue()

        dataAvailable = threading.Event()
        doneComputing = threading.Event()

        # Create new thread
        loadThread = LoadingThread(1,dataQueue)
        #learningThread.daemon = True
        loadThread.daemon=True
        # Add threads to thread list
        threads = []
        threads.append(loadThread)

        print("     >> Parrallel process start")

        # Start new Thread
        loadThread.start()
        doneComputing.set()
        # Learning process
        for i_import in range(import_init['n_import_train']):
            # Wait for data loaded
            dataAvailable.wait()
            data = dataQueue.get()
            dataAvailable.clear()
            # DO learning
            net,net_prev,y_all,yhat_all = doLearning(data, i_import, net, net_prev, y_all, yhat_all)
            doneComputing.set()

        # Wait for all threads to complete
        for t in threads:
            t.join()
```

One interesting fact is that it seems that the program crashes more often if the model sent to cuda is heavy ... Could tat be only a cuda problem?

Comment: please add some code to reproduce and if you are using try expect blocks.

Comment: In the case of a very large piece of machine learning code, I am not sure how I am suppose to share code ..

Comment: Sounds like your code gets stuck in a deadlock, e.g., your batch loading and learning thread are both waiting for each other to complete some task so they both just wait forever. We won't be able to tell anything more unless you can provide more detail about your code.

Comment: if you followed some tutorial and steps on some website to get to a point, you can also give that as details. Also, it would be a start to give the code for - From main thread I create 2 threads, one loading the next batch while the other is learning from the current batch

Comment: code added along with new observations..

Comment: use try expect around your code to print error - try:
...         asd()
...     except Exception as e:
...         print (e)

Comment: Even using `try ... except`, no error code.
However it really seems that the cause is cuda crashing. Other people reported wierd behaviour with cuda crashing with no error code.